# How to add two "targets" using linker scripts

Tags: c, assembly, linker, bootloader, linker-scripts

As I have stated previously, both my ASM and C skills are not up to scratch so please be patient with me.

I am in the process of writing a bootloader in C and have begun to rub up against the 512 byte limit, but I am not sure how to configure my linker script to split my file into two 512b segments so that I can load on from the other. My current linker script is as follows:

linker.ld

```
ENTRY(main);
SECTIONS
{    
    . = 0x7C00;    
    .text : AT(0x7C00)
    {
        _text = .;
        *(.text);
        _text_end = .;
    }
    .data :
    {
        _data = .;
        *(.bss);
        *(.bss*);
        *(.data);
        *(.rodata*);
        *(COMMON)
        _data_end = .;
    }    
    .sig : AT(0x7DFE)    
    {        
        SHORT(0xaa55);
    }    
    /DISCARD/ :
    {
        *(.note*);
        *(.iplt*);
        *(.igot*);
        *(.rel*);
        *(.comment);
    }
}
```

However, despite trying to research them online I cannot for the life of me understand this enough to go about what I am trying to do.

I can achieve what I am trying to do in assembly but I would rather keep this project solely in C

Help is massively appreciated!

And to clarify (as my initial statement seems rather nonsensical in retrospect), I need a way to load one compiled file padded to 512b into a binary with the magic word present, and then do the same to another file without the magic word with the end result being a single binary

Comment: is there a reason why you want it in a single link vs two separate programs that you combine yourself and/or you build one separately and then link the bytes as data into the other.?

Comment: If you can do it in assembly then you can do it in C, both get linked.

Comment: In linker scripts, you can specify what files to take sections from.  This should allow you to only consider sections from your boot loader file for the first 512 byte and sections from everything else for the rest.  Refer to the manual for details.

Comment: @fuz How do I go about doing that though?

Comment: @old_timer My issue is padding out the two programs correctly and splicing the provided binaries

Comment: @TTG As old_timer said, the easiest way is to have two separate linker scripts producing two separate binaries (one for the first 512 byte, one for the rest).  Then, link them separately and concatenate the results with `cat`.

Comment: If you really want to do this in a single step, I can give you an example.  But I'm busy right now; will come back later.

Comment: @fuz Ah I see what you mean - that makes sense now apologies. tysm <3

Comment: What are you using to generate the 16-bit real mode code? GCC? Are you writing the code for the first 512 bytes in assembler or C?

Comment: I have an OSDev repository with an example that does this, although it is far more complex https://github.com/mpetch/OSDev.git in particular this folder: examples/gcc-2stage-bootloader . Both stages are written in C using GCC (And I advise against this since standard GCC generates instructions that can only run on a  386+ and is fraught with gotchyas) There is a single linker script and all the low level assembly code is inlined (and inlining assembly code has its own peril and problems).

Comment: What makes mine more complex is that the linker script also computes the size of itself in 512 byte sectors which is useful if you want to know how many sectors to read in the code. The C code has a BPB (BIOS parameter block) if you need the floppy to work with USB devices in floppy device emulation. The C code in the first 512 byte sector uses `int 13h` to read the rest of the sectors into memory, sets up the segment registers as GCC needs, and then transfers control to the code in the second (and subsequent sectors). The link script assume the code for first 512 bytes is in `mbrboot.o`

Comment: The `mbrboot` code could be written in assembly as well (like NASM). An object file generated with `nasm -felf32 mbrboot.asm -o mbrboot.o`

Comment: What would really be useful to know is the particulars. What language is being used to write the code in the boot sector. What is being used in the rest of the sectors and are you trying to build an OS for real mode or 32-bit protected mode?

Comment: @MichaelPetch I have written the 512 byte bootloader in C and am using gcc flags to generate 16-bit real mode code - my issue was trying to link the two functions but that's resolved now, as I am just generating two .bin files and splicing them and then using offsets to get function pointers to the next file and calling them.

Comment: Are you using inline assembly to access the disk interrupts?

Comment: @MichaelPetch yes